In Svelte 5 how do you access children passed to a component?
In Svelte 5 how do you access children passed to a component?
+page.svelte
  <Gallery>    
    <Image src="https://www.renovatorsparadise.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/p927-768x1152.jpg"  
    url="http://www.google.com" title="Door title 1"/>

    <Image src="https://www.renovatorsparadise.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/p927-300x450.jpg"  
    url="http://www.yart.com.au" title="Door title 2"/>
  </Gallery>

How do I access the <Image> children in the Gallery?
<script>
  import Image from "./Image.svelte";

  let { children } = $props();    
</script>

<p>The gallery contains {???} images</p>

<p>The first images is {????.url} </p>

Note: I do not want to {@render children()}
I want native access of what is passed

You can't.
Snippet contents can be highly dynamic and can contain nothing and anything at all.
In situations where components are tightly coupled, a common approach is to use a shared context.
I.e. the Gallery would declare a context that Image instances can register themselves in.
E.g.
<!-- gallery.svelte -->
<script>
  import { setContext } from 'svelte';

  let { children } = $props();
  let images = $state([]);
  setContext('gallery', images);
</script>

<p>Image count: {images.length}</p>
{#if images.length > 0}
  <p>First URL: {images[0].src}</p>
{/if}

{@render children()}

<!-- image.svelte -->
<script>
  import { getContext, onDestroy } from 'svelte';

  let { src } = $props();

  const gallery = getContext('gallery');
  const img = {
    get src() {
      return src;
    }
  };
  gallery.push(img);

  onDestroy(() => gallery.splice(gallery.indexOf(img), 1));
</script>

<img {src} ... >

The logic interacting with the context could also be made conditional, in case an <Image> is used independently of a <Gallery>.
